# Creating a database for an App Service with MySQL-in-App

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I've had an App Service hosting a web site for a few years now. A few months ago, the MySQL database associated with the account simply disappeared.

Today I see I can turn on a MySQL-in-App feature. When I do so and access PHPMyAdmin, I do not seem to have any privilege, such as creating a database. For example:

```
CREATE DATABASE testdb
MySQL said: Documentation

#1044 - Access denied for user '[xxx]'@'%' to database 'testdb'
```

I am not sure what to do. Is App Service even the right resource type for hosting a website? It's a very simple one-page site with little PHP code that needs a MySQL db.

Comment: You could refer to this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/09/08/troubleshooting-faq-for-mysql-in-apppreview/) to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I ended up switching to another hosting provider before I could make sense of this situation.